# Can I deploy ASP.NET MVC 5 Application to Windows Server 2003 IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I created an `MVC5 (Framework 4.5)` website and need to deploy it into `Windows Server 2003`. `IIS 6` is running on the server. Is there anyway to run project on this server? Or what should I do to make it run? What is the newest technology can be run in `Windows Server 2003` and `IIS 6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so, yes.

I've done it with 4.0 framework, and i think 4.5 won't be a problem either. Also, no big of a deal. Here is what I've followed:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.5 will only run on Windows Server 2008 or later. You would need to downgrade to 4.0.

Unfortunately you would need to downgrade MVC as well as v5 requires .NET 4.5